# "work with a recruiter"?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word to fill in the blank in the following sentence: "I have been _____ my recruiter A, but she is currently out of office."

By this, I want to say that A has been the recruiter in charge of my case so far and I usually reach out to her for help. Can I use "work with" here? Or is there a better way to put this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need a frequency modifier and the present tense (because you are talking about frequency in the present). "I usually (normally, typically, always) work with recruiter A, but she is currently out of the office."